# If I set the Functional Level of the Forest & Domain to 2003, will Microsoft SQL 2000 still work properly?

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server, exchange-2010

Scenario: Windows Server 2003 (Domain Controller).  SQL 2000 is running on a different Windows Server 2003 machine.  SQL 2000 uses the domain to authenticate users.

In order to do an Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010 migration, I need to switch the Functional Level of the Forest and Domain.

Can I do this without causing the SQL 2000 to stop working? Or, do I need to upgrade to SQL Server 2005 or higher first?

Answer (score 6):

This should work just fine - we don't have any SQL Server 2000 systems on our network any more but we certainly had them for a couple of years after raising our domain functional level to 2003 with no problems.

Comment: This is correct. Functional Levels are DC specific. You can have any number of member servers on your domain, as long as your domain controllers all meet the requirement for the functional level.